# Bonding NIC on VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, bonding

I have an ESXi server with a DS switch configured with LACP and lag uplink with 2x10G port on the switch I'm wondering if I give 2 10G interfaces on my VM can I bond them and use that 20G uplink? I have one VM on my ESXi host.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it, the idea is that the vSwitch handles balancing between the different NICs in the bond, and your VM just talks with the vSwitch.

If you really need the performance of the full 2x10Gbps bond to a single VM, I'd just pass through the NIC to the VM instead, and do the bond in the VM instead, since if you're only hosting a single VM anyhow on the host, it's just added overhead to insert the vSwitch in the middle.

[See this guide on how to configure passthrough of a network device](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-386F225C-C890-4437-874B-449796423D4A.html)

Comment: I know that and it's not my design and I'm new to this company but anyway I try your suggestion yesterday and get this error : Module 'DevicePowerOn' power on failed. An error was received from the ESX host while powering on VM. Failed to start the virtual machine. Device 5:0.0 is not a passthrough device.

Comment: and I think the better way is to have a clean Linux installation and without ESXi, it's easier some how.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve, ESXi gives a lot of added benefits like snapshots and vMotion (even though you do cripple ESXi by using passthrough devices). The error you're getting is probably because you have the device configured in a vSwitch or as a vmkernel adapter somewhere, see https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2097215